# Запуск Cucumber Feature через Maven без JUnit тестов

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber

Есть класс для конфигурации Cucumber.

```
package test;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {
                "json:target/cucumber.json",
                "pretty", "html:target/site/cucumber-pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json"
        },
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        tags = {"~@ignore"}
)

public class CucumberRunnerTest {
}
```

Для запуска feature использую команду `mvn test "-Dcucumber.options=src/test/resources/features --tags @tag1" -PProfile1 -f pom.xml`
Данная команда запускает, не только feature с тегом `tag1`, но и все другие тесты помеченные `org.junit.Test`. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решает изменение команды запуска. Рабочее решение:

```
mvn test -Dtest=CucumberRunnerTest -Dcucumber.options="--tags @tag1" -PProfile1
```